# Combining multiple files into one and remove duplicates from the newfile

Tags: ruby, duplicates

I have data in the multiple .csv files which will download from other sources. I need to combine those data into one large file and remove the duplicates from it. Each file will have headers. Once i combine all the files, i need to get only one column from the large file as duplicate records.

*Sample Data: File1*.

> HEAD1,HEAD2,HEAD3,CR_DT,UPD_DT,UPD_BY,HEAD4 123456897,8965,N,10/18/17
>   14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N 398756398,3333,N,10/18/17 12:07,10/18/17
>   23:17,N 123456897,1234,N,10/18/17 15:27,10/18/17 23:17,N
>   908563478,8965,N,10/18/17 11:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
>   398756398,2234,N,10/18/17 12:17,10/18/17 22:17,N

*Sample Data: File2.*

> HEAD1,HEAD2,HEAD3,CR_DT,UPD_DT,UPD_BY,HEAD4 123456897,8965,N,10/18/17
>   14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N 398756398,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17
>   23:17,N 123456897,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
>   123456897,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
>   908563478,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N

*Sample Data: File3.*

> HEAD1,HEAD2,HEAD3,CR_DT,UPD_DT,UPD_BY,HEAD4 123456897,8965,N,10/18/17
>   14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N 398756398,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17
>   23:17,N 123456897,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
>   908563478,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
>   123456897,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N

Large File should the data like.

HEAD1
123456897
398756398
123456897
123456897

908563478

Please help me in this case.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you look at Ruby's [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Let's first construct the three CSV files.

```
File.write("file1.csv",
<<_
HEAD1,HEAD2,HEAD3,CR_DT,UPD_DT,HEAD4
123456897,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
398756398,3333,N,10/18/17 12:07,10/18/17 23:17,N
123456897,1234,N,10/18/17 15:27,10/18/17 23:17,N
908563478,8965,N,10/18/17 11:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
398756398,2234,N,10/18/17 12:17,10/18/17 22:17,N
_
)
  #=> 282

File.write("file2.csv",
<<_
HEAD1,HEAD2,HEAD3,CR_DT,UPD_DT,HEAD4
123456897,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
398756398,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
123456897,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
123456897,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
908563478,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
_
)
  #=> 282

File.write("file3.csv",
<<_
HEAD1,HEAD2,HEAD3,CR_DT,UPD_DT,HEAD4
123456897,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
398756398,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
123456897,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
908563478,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
123456897,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
_
)
  #=> 282
```

Notice that I have modified the file contents from what was given in the question. Firstly, the header,

```
HEAD1,HEAD2,HEAD3,CR_DT,UPD_DT,UPD_BY,HEAD4
```

denotes 7 fields (6 commas), but each subsequent row, such as

```
123456897,8965,N,10/18/17 14:17,10/18/17 23:17,N
```

has 6 fields (5 commas). I therefore removed one of the header labels, namely "UPD_BY" (a guess).

Secondly, the end-of-line characters, assuming they denote the end of each record, are in odd places. Note that Ruby will see `,N 398756398,` as a single column entry, no different than `,10/18/17 14:17,`. I therefore reformatted the data accordingly.

The desired array can be obtained as follows.

```
require 'csv'

FNames = %w|file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv|

FNames.each_with_object([]) { |fname, arr| CSV.foreach(fname) { |row| arr << row } }.
transpose.map(&:uniq)
  #=> [["HEAD1", "123456897", "398756398", "908563478"],
  #    ["HEAD2", "8965", "3333", "1234", "2234"],
  #    ["HEAD3", "N"]
  #    ["CR_DT", "10/18/17 14:17", "10/18/17 12:07", "10/18/17 15:27",
  #     "10/18/17 11:17", "10/18/17 12:17"],
  #    ["UPD_DT", "10/18/17 23:17", "10/18/17 22:17"],
  #    ["HEAD4", "N"]]
```

The question states that duplicate values should be eliminated. I therefore assumed, for example, that the first element above is desired, rather than the array given in the question (`HEAD1 123456897 398756398 123456897 123456897 908563478`), which contains two duplicates.

[This article](https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-csv-library-part/) (and the link to part 2 of the article), by Darko Gjorgjievski, is an excellent explanation of how CSV files and strings are handled in Ruby.